# How to pass function variable to c++ lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have main function  which calls to download manager function. Inside of that function, I want to be able to use the `pathUrl` inside the `onFileTaskSuccess` function. How can i pass it in ?

```
std::string  MyClass::DownloadFromUrl()
{
    std::string pathUrl ="";
    //Then i have downloader which looks like this:
    this->m_downloader->onFileTaskSuccess = [this](const network::DownloadTask& task)
    {
        //i want to use pathUrl here .. how can i pass it to here ?
        pathUrl = someValueFromTheApp;
    }
return pathUrl;
}
```

**EDIT:**
My main goal is to return value from the main function i fixed the question
which is calculated in the inner lambda function.
i also tried :
this by reference:

```
this->m_downloader->onFileTaskSuccess = [this,&pathUrl,&someValueFromTheApp](const network::DownloadTask& task)
        {
            //i want to use pathUrl here .. how can i pass it to here ?
            pathUrl = someValueFromTheApp;
        }
```

but im getting this error:

```
error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: You can check [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) for general and the specific information you are looking for.

Comment: Also, there is a StackOverflow document on [C++ lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/572/lambdas/1856/capture-by-value#t=201612161319204117505)

Comment: this is not working in my case

Answer (score 4):

[**Capture**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) `pathUrl` inside the lambda:

```
this->m_downloader->onFileTaskSuccess = [this, pathUrl](const network::DownloadTask& task)
{
    // `pathUrl` can now be used.
}
```

---

In general, you can choose between capturing by value *(i.e. making a copy)* or by reference. If you capture by reference, you're assuming that the captured object will **live at least as long as the lambda**.

In your particular case it seems like `onFileTaskSuccess` is an *asynchronous* function that will be called after `DownloadFromUrl`'s scope ends - therefore `pathUrl` should be captured by value.

---

In C++14 you may avoid an unnecessary copy by using *generalized lambda captures*:

```
this->m_downloader->onFileTaskSuccess = [this, pathUrl = std::move(pathUrl)]
    (const network::DownloadTask& task)
    {
        // `pathUrl` can now be used.
    }
```

*(The code above assumes that `pathUrl` will not be used after assigning `onFileTaskSuccess` to the lambda.)*

Comment: Thanks allot , how do i capture by reference ?

Comment: Read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture

Comment: problem when i try by reference like this : >onFileTaskSuccess = [this, &pathUrl,&DownloadPath](const network::DownloadTask& task)
{
   pathUrl = DownloadPath
}
gives me error :
error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Is `pathUrl` declared as `const`?